# Map string UID with agora generated integer UID

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, agora.io

Basically, I have a web project where I am using String username as `UID` to join the channel in the Agora video call. Recently I need to implement individual cloud recording of Agora in the project. As the cloud recording doesn't take a string as a `UID` I am facing difficulty to figure out which record file belongs to which user as the record file that generates has `UID` that is an integer. So I need to map `username` with the integer `UID`. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Happy to help but without sufficient code. It is hard to image what are you working on and what exactly would be problem. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Wish I could help you with the code but there is some "organization" related issue.

Comment: Dude, don't mind but without [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), It is hard to understand and it is hard to image what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom backend, it would be easy to store both integer and string uid for the same uuid of a user and retrieve it when needed.

**Example:** `uuid { string uid, integer uid }`

If you don't have a custom backend then you will need to map it internally using the [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/v1.0.0/index.html) which will very hard.